# is there anything wrong in this command sed -i 's/$/ \/' vcs.csh? it's not adding " \" at the end of each line in my vcs file

Tags: linux

I have used this `sed -i 's/$/ \/' vcs.csh` but it's not adding  `\` at the end of each line in my vcs file.

```
sed -i 's/$/ \/' vcs.csh
sed: -e expression #1, char 7: unterminated `s' command
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe there is some error in the typesetting of this question, but `sed -i 's/$/ /' <file>`
does not ask to add a `\` at the end of the line, nor give any errors.

This does what (edit: I thought) you want:

```
sed -i 's/$/\\/' <file>
```

(Edit: replying to the comment here as the minimarkdown gets confusing since `\` is a escape character in that too.)
The latter part of the substution (i.e. `\\`) escapes the sed command character `\`. That is, `\\` substitues in only one `\` at the place of `$`. So you can add spaces where you need them around the `\\`

Comment: Hi, Thank you for your response. it is adding now "\" at the end of the line but why I have given like this is to get line like instead of this vcs -sverilog -full64\ i need like this vcs -sverilog -full64 \ (space \) so, I'm not getting that "space" and "\" at the end of the line.

Comment: Yes, it's working now. thanks.

Comment: sed -i 's/$/ \\/' vcs.csh

Comment: If an answer has helped you solve your problem feel free to mark the answer as accepted and upvote.